# Azure Application Gateways with existing back-end IPs

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I'm writing an ARM template to deploy an Application Gateway. The "back-end" servers already exist and have private IP addresses.

If I create an app gateway through the portal. I'm able to select the VM(s) that I want to be part of the back-end pool. I'm trying to create this in the ARM template, and I'm not having any success. The ARM template deploys without any errors, but when I check the back-end pool, there are not any resources tied to it.

Here's what the applicable section of my ARM template looks like:

```
"backendAddressPools": [
          {
            "name": "PublishPool",
            "properties": {
              "backendIPConfigurations": [
                {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/ipConfigurations', parameters('networkInterfaceName'), parameters('ipConfigurationName'))]"
                }
              ],              
            }
          }
        ]
```

I've managed to get it working by using the IP address itself (the JSON looks a bit different if you go that route), but that may cause problems if the IP addresses change down the road; I'd rather use references to the network interface itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party here, but I hope this helps future internet travellers.

It's extremely non-obvious, but you have to define the backend pool *in the interface configuration as well*.

This is my ARM template configuring the IP Configuration for the interfaces I want to add to the backend pool:

```
"properties": {
    "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
    "subnet": {
        "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', variables('clientNetworkName')), '/subnets/', variables('clientPriSubnetName'))]"
    },
    "applicationGatewayBackendAddressPools": [
        {
            "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', variables('appGWName')), '/backendAddressPools/appGatewayBackendPool')]"
        }
    ]
}
```

(Note the section for `applicationGatewayBackendAddressPools` which resolves the resource ID of my application gateway).

Then in the ARM template section for the gateway backend pools itself:

```
"backendAddressPools": [{
    "name": "appGatewayBackendPool",
    "properties": {
        "backendIPConfigurations" : [
            {
                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',concat('networkInterface-',variables('webBaseName'),'1-pri')),'/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1')]"
            },
            {
                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',concat('networkInterface-',variables('webBaseName'),'2-pri')),'/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1')]"
            }
        ]
    }                   
}],
```

This adds two interfaces (identified as `networkInterface-client-web01-pri` and `networkInterface-client-web02-pri`) to the backend pool.

Thanks to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/issues/110) for pointing me in the right direction, and no thanks to Microsoft for not having any documentation about this at all for obviously a few years now.

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/ipConfigurations',
>   parameters('networkInterfaceName'), parameters('ipConfigurationName'))

If you use like this, Azure could not find your NIC. You could check [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/). You could find backup pool configuration like below:

```
  "backendIPConfigurations": [
                {
                  "id": "/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/shuitest/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/shui1482/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1"
                }
              ],
```

So, you should modify your json such as below:

```
properties": {
              "backendIPConfigurations": [
                {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaceName'), 'ipConfigurations',parameters('ipConfigurationName'))]"
                }
              ],
```

Comment: I tried that yesterday (and tried it again this morning just in case I made a mistake yesterday) and I get the following error when I deploy the ARM template `'Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': the type 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces' requires '1' resource name argument(s).` I agree that the way you have it is more intuitive, but I think you are supposed to describe the entire resource path in a single string, then provide N number of arguments, and N is dependent upon which type of resource you are describing.

Comment: If possible, could you share your template. I'd like to test in my lab and give you the result. Also, please remove sensitive information.

Comment: I've genericized the file. Hopefully while doing so, I have not made any mistakes. The template assumes the virtual network and subnets exists as well as the resources that are configured for the backend pool. https://pastebin.com/rshL4Gi9.  Thanks.

Comment: @BrianBall I met the same error with you. I test many times and diff with other official templates, I could not solve this issue. I suggest you could solve this issue firstly. You could ask a new question about this.

Comment: Ask a new question about what? I thought we were still on my original question. If you are referring to the proper way to use `resouceId()`, I have verified that the way I have it stated in the question is correct. I verified it by setting an output variable in the ARM template to the resourceId expression and the result I got matches what Azure Resource Explorer has for the Id.